# How to convert the code table to div as the most optimal and standards?

Tags: css, optimization, standards, css-tables

Can you rewrite my code table on the div so that it is the most optimal and consistent with the standards?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What do you mean by `code table`?

Comment: i.e. how convert table to div

Comment: AFAIK you need to do it manually.

Comment: By using the correct markup, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I mean, can you rewrite my code table on the div so that it is the most optimal and consistent with the standards? and give me ready code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving you the most basic layout:(P.S. Haven't tried it in browser)

HTML:

```
<div>
         <div class = "forumline bigRow" >

            <div class="cat row">
              {FORUM_NAME}
            </div>

            <div class="cat row">
              {FORUM_DESC}
            </div>


         </div>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.bigRow{width:100%;}

.row{width: 100%;}
```

P.S: This works when I use twitter Bootstrap in my project very well.

Comment: thanks a lot but from what I know writing the same divs is not too good <div><div><div></div></div></div>

Comment: What do you mean writing the same divs, classes are supposed to be flexible, and therefore re-usable.

Comment: Same DIVs? Couldn't get you? What do you mean by same DIVs? Explain?

Comment: whether the use of so many divs is good?

Comment: @seweryns, looked at your HTML code, why don't you use the "Definition Lists". I mean using `<dl>` `<dt>` tags?

Comment: hearing this for first time.
But how I work or advised to work acc. to standards is for each row there should be a div but for data/text inside you can use <Span> or <P> or <h3>, anything. Really your choice after that.

Comment: Use the appropriate markup. Think about whether you need to use `<div>`s, or is there a more semantic tag to markup your content..

Comment: I would recommended using `<dl>` definition list suits for the layout you made..

Comment: well it will create somebody code <dl> <dt> etc?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Read this for more explanation on this type of structure. Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i've created for you.

```
 <ul class="forumline">
    <li><span class="gensmall_new_h1">{FORUM_NAME}</span></li>
    <li><span class="gensmall_new">{L_TAGS}: {SEOTAGS}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the css for it

```
.forumline {background:#fff; padding:3px; list-style: none;}
ul.forumline li{background-color:#e7e7e7;border-bottom: 1px solid #c7c7c7; padding: 10px;  }
ul.forumline li:hover{background-color:#fff;border-bottom: 1px solid #c7c7c7; padding: 10px; cursor: pointer; }
ul.forumline li:first-child{border-top: 4px solid #333;}
```

Other wise you can also use other plugins like 
    http://bit.ly/OsLoYO

[Click here to see demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kijanmaharjan/FXBp5/)!